# Windows - How to prevent minimizing the current opened app when clicking on its icon in the taskbar?

Tags: windows, taskbar

Is there a way to set windows so that if I click the icon of the current opened app it will not be minimized?

You might ask why do I want this. Sometimes I get distracted, think that I want to use the current app when it's actually maximized, click on the icon in the taskbar but then I see that I get the last maximized app so I click it again to get it back. When distracted, this behavior is confusing.

So, other than fixing me, is there a software solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Umm, there used to be something like taskbar tweaker, I don't know if they still work, but you can look for them.

Comment: You're not alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following saaransh garg's answer (thanks!), this is the solution.

Download and install 7+ Taskbar Tweaker from https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker

Run it.

Right click the tray icon (the one near the clock, not the one in the taskbar) and choose Advanced options.

Add the value according to the instructions here

https://tweaker.userecho.com/en/communities/1/topics/469-add-option-to-disable-minimize-window-when-clicking-already-active-window

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).